# Async variable and and dynamic variable not the same type

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have a variable called grayVal, it tells me the grayscale value of a pixel  what my camera is being pointed at. Obviously this number is constantly changing when I move the camera around. My Issue is that when I pass grayVal in an async with a loop to test how long it takes for grayVal to pass a threshold, the number never changes no matter what I point the camera at. I was told that grayVal (in onCameraFrame) and grayVal (in doInBackground) ar not that same type. I have changed them to doubles, but it had the same result.

in UI thread

```
volatile double [] grayVal;


@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    grayMat = inputFrame.gray();
    double [] grayPixel = grayMat.get(100,100);
    grayVal = grayPixel;
    Log.i("Mat Value", String.valueOf(grayVal[0]));
    return grayMat;
}
```

AsyncTask

```
public class startTestAsync extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, Void> {       
int testAmount;
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Double...grayVal) {
    for (testAmount = 0; testAmount < 5000; testAmount++) {
        Log.i("Mat Value Async", String.valueOf(grayVal[0]));
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
}
}
```

logcat

```
08-26 04:51:21.873  19683-20612/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value Async﹕ 234.0
08-26 04:51:21.873  19683-20612/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value Async﹕ 234.0
08-26 04:51:21.873  19683-20379/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value﹕ 25.0
08-26 04:51:21.873  19683-20612/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value Async﹕ 234.0
08-26 04:51:21.873  19683-20612/bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester I/Mat Value Async﹕ 234.0
```

Comment: why do you access `grayVal` once this way: `grayVal = grayPixel;` (like a primitive) and once this way: `grayVal[0]` (like an array)? What happens if you change it to `grayVal[0] = grayMat.get(100,100);` Can you link your full code at pastebin again?

Comment: `protected Void doInBackground(Double...grayVal)` Your method parameter has the same name as the global variable. Change either of their name, so that the global variable has a unique name!.Don't name a method parameter like a GLOBAL VARIABLE!

Comment: this is all my code http://pastebin.com/tZkFbJUZ

Comment: I change `Double...grayVal` to `Double...grayValAsync`, still the same results

Comment: please test my answer. In addition, how/where is `doInBackground` called and what parameter do you give to it? You probably have to change that definition to `doInBackground(volatile Double...grayValAsync)`, otherwise the compiler won't see any changes on that parameter, because it isn't changed in the method itself...

Comment: I'm not a Java pro, so I have to ask another thing: Is `Void doInBackground(Double...grayVal)` passing parameters by `reference` or by `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try all those changes at the same time:

```
volatile double grayValGlobal;
```

and

```
@Override
                    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
                        grayMat = inputFrame.gray();
                        double [] grayPixel = grayMat.get(100,100);
                        grayValGlobal = grayPixel[0];
                        Log.i("Mat Value", String.valueOf(grayValGlobal ));
                        return grayMat;
                    }
```

and

```
public class startTestAsync extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, Void> {
        double[] timeArray = new double[500]; // set array
        double rating = 0;
        double lagStartTime;
        double lagEndTime;
        double lagTimeResult;
        int testAmount;
        int cnt;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Double...grayVal) {

            for (testAmount = 0; testAmount < 5000; testAmount++) {

                Log.i("Mat Value Async", String.valueOf(grayValGlobal));
                lagStartTime = System.nanoTime(); //start lagTimer start
                    }
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            //Do something
        }

    }
```

and post the result

EDIT:
`volatile double grayValGlobal;` isn't really global at the position where it is placed (inside the class). So my guess (not a java pro): `doInBackground` somewhere gets grayVal(Global) as input parameter. But that parameter isn't passed by reference, so only one fixed value is used during the whole test.

Comment: on `grayValGlobal = grayMat.get(100,100);` android studio says "Incompatible types, Required double, found double []"

Comment: can't resolve grayValGlobal in  `Log.i("Mat Value Async", String.valueOf(grayValGlobal));` in the Async

Comment: ah, that variable isn't global, because it is in that `class testActivity` ... where is `doInBackground` called from?

Comment: in `startTestAsync.java`

Comment: In your linked code I only see the definition, but not where it is called and what input parameter(s) it gets.

Comment: nice to hear that! how did you solve it? making the variable really "global"?

Comment: I moved the async from the external file to the activity file. Now all I need to do is be able to edit text views from the async `doInBackground()` and my app is pretty much done.